# К вопросу о свойствах русского языка (9)

Tags: орфография, троллинг

Предположим, я предложу, чтобы русские писали неопределённые наречия с приставкой "кой-" без дефиса (например, "койгде" вместо "кой-где", "койкуда" вместо "кой-куда").

**Вопрос:** Противоречит ли указанное предложение хотя бы одному свойству русского языка?

Comment: Можно оффтопик? 
Если, к примеру, мы бы вам сказали, что вы - выхухоль, могли бы вы за это на нас обидеться?

Comment: Он на нас в суд подаст!

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите здесь:[К вопросу о свойствах русского языка (9.1)](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/23714/%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%83-%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%85-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0-9-1?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=23726#23726)

Comment: Посмотрел.

Answer (score 0):

противоречит правилам)) Местоимения кое-кто и кое-что при сочетании с предлогами пишутся раздельно (в три слова), например: кое у кого, кое в чем. Местоимение кой-какой при сочетании с предлогом пишется в три слова: кое с какими, или в два: с кое-каким